# Should column labels for numbers be aligned right?

Tags: tables, labels, grid, column-headers

In a grid structure, I understand you should right-align numbers in the cells.

Should you also right-align the headers for these columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column headers aren't part of the data, therefore it's good if these are visually distinguishable from the cell data. This can be achieved by font style, tile background and alignment. So, using center alignment for your column header but not for your cell content is no violation against best practices, on the contrary.

Comment: I plan on having the headers bolded or otherwise distinguished from the data. Not to mention the fact that it's text and not numbers. But should the alignment of the headers align with the data, or should the headers just be consistent in their style across the columns?

Comment: @DLeh I realized I used some confusing phrasing in my answer, it's updated now. The essence is the same though, you don't violate any best practices by using a different alignment for a column header that you do for the cells of that column. It will actually aid scanability since the elements become even more visually distinguishable.